# singleton at the boot of application

Tags: spring-boot, singleton

I'm creating a small game where I would like to have a game room and a bunch of games in the game room. This would be a spring boot application. So I was thinking of starting the GameRoom at the start of the application. Then whenever a new game is created, I will add it to the list of games in the game roon. Is is a good idea? Or are there any potential pitfalls.

```
public class GameRoon{

   private static GameRoom instance = null;
   List<Game> games = new ArrayList();

   private GameRoom() {}

   public static GameRoom getIsntance() {
    if(instance == null) {
       instance = new GameRoom();
    }
    return instance;
  }
}
```

The above is my unfinished singleton.. I have 2 questions.
1. Is it a good idea to start this during spring-boot start up?
2. Is it better to use singleton like this in spring-boot or is there a better way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Singletons are highly debated and you will always find reasons for using it and for not.

In my opinion if your class responsibility is to hold a state (think of a registry with some data) which is shared within the application I don't see any problem. It is clear that you share the data and must be sure to govern concurrent access.

The main drawback of Singleton is **testing**: you have a global state but ideally during unit testing you want to test some code without relying on the singleton class (instead a mock). You can still solve this thanks to Spring: define the GameRoom as Spring bean (default scope is Singleton) which is injected like any other bean. This allows to mock it during unit testing, even if underneath there is a singleton behavior.

Comment: would it work if I made the `GameRoom` a spring bean and every time a new game is created, I would do a new Game() and add it to a list. Would this work with concurrent access. Or does `Game` also need to be a singleton/bean for it to work?

Comment: GameRoom is the singleton (one instance in the entire app), you can then add/remove Game in the list (Game is just a plein Java class). In terms of concurrency you could add methods to add/remove Game from the list so you control how the list changes